# Verifying Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, verification

I'm hoping someone can help me. I'm pretty new to MySQL, so I'm not fully versed in all of its capabilities.

I was given a spreadsheet with data in the format:

```
child Name |Gender| dob| class|Parent name|parent phone|parent address
```

I separated this into 3 tables which consist of:

```
Child_details   Datatype    Required    Key
Child_id    INT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL    Primary
Child_fname VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL     
Child_sname VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL     
Gender  Enum(M,F) NOT NULL  NOT NULL     
DoB DATE NOT NULL   NOT NULL     
Parent/Carer id INTEGER NOT NULL    Foreign


Parent_details  Datatype    Required    Key
Parent_id   INT AUTO_INCREMENT  NOT NULL    Primary
Parent_title    CHAR(5)      
Paren _fname    VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL     
Parent/_sname   VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL     
Parent _Add1    VARCHAR(25)     NOT NULL     
Parent _Add2    VARCHAR(25)          
Parent _city    VARCHAR(25)          
Parent _Pcode   VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL     
Parent _phone   VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL     


Activity    Datatype    Required    Key
Activity_name   CHAR(8) NOT NULL     
Activity_day    CHAR(5) NOT NULL
```

Then made a bridging table  for a roll call list with the activity data. Some of the children do one class, some do all three:

```
Schedule    Datatype    Required    Key
Child_id    INT NOT NULL    Foreign, Composite
Activity_id INT NOT NULL    Foreign, Composite
```

I’m trying to write a query that I can run to check if the data I have entered is correct. I want to be able to view the results in the same format as the spreadsheet. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',Child_fname,Child_sname) AS 'Child Name',
Child_gender AS 'Gender',
Child_dob AS 'DoB',
COUNT Activity_name AS Activities,
CONCAT_WS(' ',Parent_title,Parent_fname,Parent_sname) AS 'Parent/Carer name',
Parent_phone AS 'Parent/Carer phone',
CONCAT_WS(' ',Parent_add1,Parent_add2,Parent_city,Parent_pcode) AS 'Parent/Carer Address'
FROM Child,Activity,Parent;
```

But the results I get show each child does all of the activities and that they all have each. Am I missing something obvious,  do I need to use COUNT DISTINCT or GROUP BY, or have I created the tables wrong?

Any information anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.
I hope I have provided enough information, but not too much.

Comment: Your `Activity` table does not appear to contain a column to which the `Activity_id` field in the `Schedule` table references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell MySQL how to join the tables together (without this information, it joins every row of each table with every row of every other table, as you describe):

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
       Child
  JOIN Schedule USING (Child_id)
  JOIN Activity USING (Activity_id) -- does this column exist in Activity?
  JOIN Parent   USING (Parent_id)   -- does this column exist in Child?
```

You might want to follow some [tutorials on SQL `JOIN`](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+join+tutorial).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go. You are right, I do need to do some more tutorials on SQL. My college recommended w3schools but I didn't find it that helpful.